# Приложение на Flask падает если сделать >2 запросов сразу

Tags: html, python, веб-программирование, flask

Имеется приложение Flask принимающее request.form от клиента и выполняющее обработку. Особенность в том, что обработка данных выполняется примерно 7 секунд и, чтобы пользователю не приходилось смотреть на белый экран и статус страницы "Ожидание" я сделал внутри функции app.route многопоточность через Thread, которая вызывает внешнюю функцию, выполняющую 7-секундный процесс, пока на стороне клиента откроется новая страница, готовая принять новые данные (пока идет работа с предыдущими). 
Проблема возникает, когда отправить второй запрос до того как выполнится первый. Бэкэнд просто перестает работать выдавая:

```
    raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.IMAP4.error: SEARCH command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']
```

и программа не работает не будет полностью перезапущена.
Для ясности: программа берет данные и далее идет работа с imap, который обращается к почтовому серверу для загрузки нужных писем.
Может есть способ в колбе типа:

```
  @app.route('/res_page', methods=['POST'])
  def func():
    a = request.form['a']
    request_mail(a) # Та самая "долгая" функция  
    return redirect('/') # Страница, которая должна возвращаться сразу после получения от данных от клиента
```

сделать так, чтобы request_mail() выполнялся параллельно после получения данных request, но не завершался после return объемлющей функции func()?
Моя реализация представлена примерно так:

```
def processing(ads, description, time, req):
    global arg
    # loading data
@app.route('/res_page', methods=['POST']) 
def res_page() -> 'html':
    global ads, description, time, req
    ads = request.form['ads']
    description = request.form.get('description')
    ads = ''.join(list(ads))
    description = ''.join(list(description))
    time = get_
    time()
    req = request.form['res']
    prc = Thread(target=processing, args=(ads, description, time, req))
    prc.start()
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону gevent. Мне кажется, для вашего случая это наиболее оптимальное решение либо celery https://defpython.ru/ispolzovanie_Celery_vo_Flask

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, [Flask спроектирован под однопоточное использование](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/design/#thread-locals). Долгие задачи лучше перекладывать на очереди задач, типа [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Во-вторых, imaplib не является потокобезопасной. Наконец, использование глобальных переменных - само по себе плохая идея, а в многопоточной среде особенно.

Comment: По поводу глобальных переменных: а что, если нужно сравнивать новое значение из функции полученной в app.route со старым, которое уничтожается при каждой загрузке страницы? Я применил глобальные переменные для того, чтобы сохранять и сравнивать значения на протяжении всей сессии.

Comment: Насчет потокобезопасности imaplib: а что, если основные данные с которыми работает приложения - это новые письма в gmaiil? Есть другой потокобезопасный способ работы с почтовым сервером?

Comment: Является ли Celery решением для проблемы потокобезопасности imaplib?

Comment: Всегда можно обойтись без глобальных переменных. Проблему с imaplib можно решить только с помощью _thread confinement_, если алгоритм это позволяет. Celery не использует потоки, поэтому и проблем не возникнет.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, Возможно глупый вопрос, но поиск в интернете дал мало ответов: "thread confinement" это из функционала библиотеки threading? Или это из функционала Celery? Возможно у вас будут ссылки, где можно найти больше ответов...

Comment: Это один из паттернов разработки многопоточного кода, основанный на том, что потоки не имеют разделяемого состояния. Честно говоря, не знаю хороших материалов по многопоточному программированию в Python, так как к моменту знакомства с языком уже имел большой опыт в этой области. Да и не думаю, что python-программисту стоит обращать много внимания на эту область. Лучше уделить больше внимания асинхронности.